# Unable to delete a row in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I created a small function and small trigger. When I run the simplest `DELETE` query, I only see a notice and a context message in the console (no warning and no error messages), but still this `DELETE` query has no effect (the record stays in table and is not deleted). The function and trigger look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_layers_before_del () RETURNS trigger 
AS $$
DECLARE
    table_name text := (SELECT concat ('layer_', OLD.id::text, '_'));
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE '
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || quote_ident(table_name) || ' CASCADE
    ';
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE  plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_layers_del_befor
BEFORE DELETE ON layers FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_layers_before_del();
```

And this how `DELETE` command looks like:

```
DELETE FROM layers where id = 31
```

So, if I run:

```
DELETE FROM layers WHERE id = 31;
SELECT * FROM layers WHERE id = 31;
```

then it returns a record with `id = 31`.

The notice says, that "table "layer_31_" does not exist, skips ...". The context message simply prints `EXECUTE` statement. So, if there are no errors, why `DELETE` command is not commited?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because your function returns `NULL`. As per [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/trigger-definition.html):

> Trigger functions invoked by per-row triggers can return a table row
>   (a value of type HeapTuple) to the calling executor, if they choose. A
>   row-level trigger fired before an operation has the following choices:
>
> - It can return NULL to skip the operation for the current row. This instructs the executor to not perform the row-level operation that
>     invoked the trigger (the insertion, modification, or deletion of a
>     particular table row).
> - For row-level INSERT and UPDATE triggers only, the returned row
>     becomes the row that will be inserted or will replace the row being
>     updated. This allows the trigger function to modify the row being
>     inserted or updated.
>
> A row-level BEFORE trigger that does not intend to cause either of
>   these behaviors must be careful to return as its result the same row
>   that was passed in (that is, the NEW row for INSERT and UPDATE
>   triggers, the OLD row for DELETE triggers).

So, what you need is to `RETURN OLD;`